# In what situation might Text be different from ValueText

Tags: c#, roslyn

In Roslyn (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis), `SyntaxToken`s have `Text` and `ValueText` fields. In all of the situations that I've observed so far, these two values are the same. `ValueText` has documentation while `Text` does not. As far as I can tell, that's the only difference.

Why do both exist? In what situation would they be different, and why?

Answer (score 14):

> Why do both exist?

Because they're sometimes different and both are useful.

> In what situation would they be different, and why?

```
int @interface = 123;
```

The `Text` of the `@interface` token is `@interface`.  The `ValueText` is `interface`.  The text tell you *what is the text as it appeared in the source code*.  The value text tells you *logically, what is the text of this thing?* An escaped keyword used as an identifier is logically the text of the keyword; that's the name of the identifier.

There are other situations in which the text and the value text can be different; see if you can find some.

Comment: Taking a guess without testing it: `\u0061\u0062\u0063` probably has a `Text` of `\u0061\u0062\u0063` and a `ValueText` of `abc`.

Comment: Number literals is another possibility: `1.2f`; Text is `1.2f`, ValueText is `1.2`.